# TASM: Generating a simple calculator

Tags: arrays, assembly, macros, tasm

i am trying to make a simple calculator in TASM, its not done yet, i am trying to figure out addition part but i am stuck because of Operands type do not match, here is what i have;

```
;FILENAME: SimpleClc.asm
;FILE FORMAT: EXE
PAGE 55,132
.386

STACK_SEG SEGMENT STACK USE16

        DB 100 DUP(?)

STACK_SEG ENDS

DATA_SEG SEGMENT 'DATA' USE16

ADDITION    MACRO   Result,Char1,Char2


        MOV AX,Char1
        CWD
        ADD AX,Char2,
        MOV Result,AX

ENDM

SUBTRACTION MACRO   Char1, Char2

        SUB Char1,Char2
ENDM

DIVISION    MACRO   Char1, Char2

        DIV Char1,Char2
ENDM

MULTIPLICATION  MACRO   Char1, Char2

        MUL Char1,Char2
ENDM

Mainmsg   DB 'Please enter a algebraic command line: $'
ErMessage DB 'Error!!', 0DH, 0AH
          DB 'INPUT FORMAT:Operand1 Operator Operand',0DH, 0AH
          DB 'Operand: Decimal Numbers',0DH, 0AH
          DB 'Operator: + -'

INCHAR  DB 21
Res     DB 10 dup('$')
INCDAT  DB 21 dup('$')
VarX    DB 10 dup('$')
VarY    DB 10 dup('$')



DATA_SEG ENDS

CODE_SEG SEGMENT PARA 'CODE' PUBLIC USE16

ASSUME CS:CODE_SEG, DS:DATA_SEG, SS:STACK_SEG

MAIN PROC FAR

        PUSH DS ;INITIATE THE PROGRAM
        XOR AX,AX
        PUSH AX
        MOV AX,DATA_SEG
        MOV DS,AX

    AGAIN:

        LEA DX,Mainmsg ;PRINT MESSAGE
        MOV AH,9
        INT 21H

        MOV DX, OFFSET INCHAR
        MOV AH,0AH
        INT 21H

        MOV DX, OFFSET INCHAR
        MOV AH,0AH
        INT 21H

        LEA DX,INCDAT ;Writing the incoming input
        MOV AH,9
        INT 21H

        MOV DI,OFFSET INCDAT



        MOV AL, [DI]
        CMP AL, 9
        JLE OPERAND     ; jump if less or equal
        JG ERRORMESSAGE ; jump if not less or equal
        INC DI

        OPERAND:
        MOV AL, [DI]
        CMP AL, '+'
        JE  LASTOPERAND
        CMP AL, '-'
        JE  LASTOPERAND
        CMP AL, '*'
        JE  LASTOPERAND
        CMP AL, '/'
        JE LASTOPERAND
        JMP ERRORMESSAGE

        INC DI

        LASTOPERAND:
        MOV AL, [DI]
        CMP AL, 9
        JLE OPERATION   ; jump if less or equal
        JG ERRORMESSAGE ; jump if not less or equal

        OPERATION:

        CMP AL, '+'
        JE ADDITION1
        JMP AGAIN
ADDITION1:
            MOV DI,OFFSET INCDAT
            MOV AL,[DI]
            MOV VarX,AL
            MOV AL,[DI+2]
            MOV VarY,AL
            ADDITION Res,VarX,VarY
            JMP AGAIN
        CMP AL, '-'
        JE  SUBTRACTION1
        JMP AGAIN
SUBTRACTION1:

        CMP AL, '*'
        JE  MULTIPLICATION1
        JMP AGAIN
MULTIPLICATION1:

            JMP AGAIN

        CMP AL, '/'
        JE DIVISION1
        JMP AGAIN
DIVISION1:



        ERRORMESSAGE:
        LEA DX,ErMessage ;PRINT MESSAGE
        MOV AH,9
        INT 21H


MAIN    ENDP
CODE_SEG ENDS
END MAIN
```

I know it looks quite messy right now, it is just because i am trying bunch of things at the same time, btw my calculator will not calculate results that are greater than 10. Thanks for help.Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: What does _"Operands type do not match"_ mean? What input did you give to your program, what was your expected result, and what was the actual result?

Comment: well, since i get error, it does not compile. As i have researched, it is about bit diffrence but i could not figure out how to fix that. my error is in line 123-125-126, that is in addition1

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: Operand types do not match(123)(125) and ADDITION(5) Extra characters on line(126) these 3 errors

Answer (score 0):

Ups, it is hard to digit all the linenumbers.

To place code inside the data segment is not the best idea.

For what this following instruction are good?:

```
    PUSH DS    ; pushing the old address of DS to the stack
    XOR AX,AX
    PUSH AX    ; pushing a zero word to the stack
```

And at last how to terminate the programm?

I am not sure, but maybe the errors occur for using labelnames that starts similar like the names of assembler mnemonics.

And why using the input function one after another for to override the same buffer?

```
    MOV DX, OFFSET INCHAR
    MOV AH,0AH
    INT 21H

    MOV DX, OFFSET INCHAR
    MOV AH,0AH
    INT 21H
```